# Кольцевой показ изображений на js

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не знаю, как реализовать показ изображений по кольцу, чтобы каждый следующий нажатый элемент был по середине.
[введите сюда описание изображения][2]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сам реализовывал через сокрытие и раскрытие блоков, но, если показывать последние элементы и 1 первый, то последний элемент, который должен быть поставлен в середину, остается в конце

Comment: Нажатая картинка должна просто встать по середине или там должна происходить анимация кручения по кольцу? Если есть пример где можно это посмотреть, то приложите это к вопросу, пожалуйста

Comment: Хорошо, конечно, с анимацией. Но и без нее можно, хотя бы понять как нужно делать...